# Difference between dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeinterval) sincedate:(nsdate *) and (nsdate *) dateByAddingTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

what is the difference between the two statements

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDate *tomarow = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
NSDate *nextday = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60*60*24 sinceDate:today];
```

Comment: @InderKumarRathore - i'm getting the same value for both statements.what is the difference between them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only difference between the two methods is that one is a class method and the other is an instance method.

Following code snippet demonstrates the use of both methods:

```
// Today's Date
NSDate *today = [NSDate new];

// Date With Class Method
NSDate *tomorrow1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:60*60*24 sinceDate:today];
NSLog(@"Date from class method: %@", tomorrow1);

// Date With Instance Method
NSDate *tomorrow2 = [today dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24];
NSLog(@"Date from instance method: %@", tomorrow2);
```

The above code snippet will give the output like following:

> Date from class method: 2012-12-27 09:35:15 +0000
>
> Date from instance method: 2012-12-27 09:35:15 +0000

for more information , see [NSDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: could you do the same by passing negative vale `-60*60*24`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore and here we go: tomarrow 2012-12-25 09:46:50 +0000, nextday 2012-12-25 09:46:50 +0000!! whats wrong?

Comment: Nothing is wrong, I'm on windows right now so can't check. That's why I told you. Anyways +1 f

Comment: @Dpk : Sorry man, my mistake... I am sleeping... anywaz +1 for your answer :)